# Data set of particulate matter concentrations in Graz, Austria

Tags: data-request, time-series, environment

I am looking for a data set that which observations are half-hourly measurements of the concentration (measured in μgm −3 ) of particulate matter with an aerodynamic diameter of less than 10μm, abbreviated PM10, in ambient air taken in Graz, Austria from October 1, 2010 until March 31, 2011.

The Data set is used in

- Aue, A., Dubart Norinho, D., & Hörmann, S. (2012). On the prediction
  of functional time series. Submitted for publication.
- Hörmann, S., Kidziński, Ł., & Hallin, M. (2015). Dynamic functional
  principal components. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society:
  Series B (Statistical Methodology), 77(2), 319-348.

There is a broken link in the second publication:

http://wileyonlinelibrary.com/journal/rss-datasets

I followed citations to

- Stadlober, E. Hörmann, S. and Pfeiler, (2008). Quality and
  performance of a PM10 daily fore- casting model. Atmospheric
  Environment 42, 1098–1109.

But can not find the data anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the link has become broken after the Wiley Online Library redesign and restructuring.

Now this link should be the [Please click here to access the full dataset archive](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1467-9868/homepage/seriesb_datasets.htm) link from [this page](https://rss.pericles-prod.literatumonline.com/hub/journal/14679868/series-b-datasets). However, that new link is broken too.

I don't think that this unavailability is intentional, a few months ago those datasets [were available](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810085118/http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1467-9868/homepage/seriesb_datasets.htm).

I'd suggest you contact the Royal Statistical Society or the authors. The corresponding author of the second publication is Siegfried Hörmann.

**Update**

Check [this link](https://wol-prod-cdn.literatumonline.com/pb-assets/hub-assets/rss/Datasets/Vol_77_2015-1521879345620.zip).

Comment: I have followed your advice and wrote to Hormann. I hope to get a response.

Comment: @Manuel, did you get a response?

Comment: Yes I got the data from Professor Hormann. In very short time.